# Send a broadcast to an Activity that is not in the foreground

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a background service that has a CountdownTimer. As the CountdownTimer counts down i send a broadcast to an Activity. When the CountdownTimer has counted down then the Activity is alerted and i can stop the service and unregister the receiver.

I have moved the normal receiver unregistering method from onStop and onPause into my own method that i call once a broadcast is received with "timer_finished". This is so i can move away from the Activity without unregistering.

Everything works fine if the user is currently viewing the Activity. If the user moves away from the Activity, the CoundownTimer is still running but the Activity is not receiving the broadcasts.

How can I do this so that the Activity receives the final broadcast "timer_finished"?

```
public class CountDownBroadcastService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = CountDownBroadcastService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.carefreegroup.rr3.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {       
            super.onCreate();

            mContext = this;

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");


            cdt = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                    bi.putExtra("timer_status", "timer_not_finished");
                    sendBroadcast(bi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");

                    bi.putExtra("timer_status", "timer_finished");


                    sendBroadcast(bi);

                }
            };

            cdt.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            cdt.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {       
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {       
            return null;
        }
}
```

.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "start of oncreate");

        setContentView(R.layout.loneworker);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setTitle("Lone Worker");
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        tvCountDown = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvloneworkercountdown);
        callFinished = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlwcallfinished);


        callFinished.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e(TAG, "inside callFinished");
                //maybe alert carer is safe***************************************

                setCountDownFinished();

            }
        });




        startService(new Intent(this, CountDownBroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Started service");






    }//end of onCreate



    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();        
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(CountDownBroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
        }



    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            //Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);    

            String status = intent.getStringExtra("timer_status");

            if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("timer_not_finished")){

                    tvCountDown.setText("Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("timer_finished")){

                setCountDownFinished();
            }
        }
    }//end of updateGUI


    public void setCountDownFinished(){

        tvCountDown.setText("0");
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broacast receiver");

        stopService(new Intent(this, CountDownBroadcastService.class));
        Log.e(TAG, "Stopped CountDownBroadcastService");

    }// end of setCountDownFinished()




}
```

Comment: Kindly help me to understand, is your activity is in pause state or destroyed when you try to broadcast

Comment: @AttiqurRehman It works fine when the Activity is in the foreground. It doesn't work when i click the back button and say navigate to another Activity. i don't override any of the Activity lifecycle methods, so i presumed the Activity would still be on the stack and maybe in a paused state.

Comment: can you tell us why the broadcastreceiver must live in an Activity instead of having a stand-alone-broadcastreceiver that does the "stop the service and unregister the receiver." If the activity is not visible then it-s gui must not be updated

Comment: @k3b it is just the way i have done it. Given what i want to acheive would the receiver make more sense in its own class?

Comment: @turtleboy, lemme know my explanation and answer works. Otherwise I have a shortcut technique to do so

Comment: Are you familiar with using EventBus?

Comment: @MuchOverflow no i'm not, what is it?

Comment: @tutleboy It is used as a backbone in Pub/Sub design pattern. Have a read at this and see if it can help you http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: @MuchOverflow ok thanks for that. I will use open source solutions if there is no way of acheiving the desired functionality in Android. I just find it hard to believe there is nothing in Android that works for what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you register a broadcast receiver programmatically in an
>   activity, it will not get broadcasts when the activity is paused. The
>   BroadcastReceiver docs are not as clear as they could be on this
>   point. They recommend unregistering on onPause solely to reduce system
>   overhead.
>        If you want to receive events even when your activity is not in the foreground, register the receiver in your manifest using the
>   receiver element.

Comment: If i register a receiver using the receiver element in the manifest, how do i then update the UI if the Activity is in the foreground and how do i send the "timer_finished" String to the Activity if the Activity is not in the foreground?

Comment: You can handle this thing via Service because you just want to close the counter not to again show the activity....
If you really wanna show your activity, then you start the activity -- i will suggest you to launch activity with launchMode= "SingleInstance"